# Chrome and Mobile not rendering the same results as Firefox - Bootstrap

Tags: css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have an input field in a container, everything works fine in Firefox but when I tested it on mobile (Chrome & Safari) the text field overlap to the right. I have the same issue with Chrome desktop.

I tried using clearfix but it didn't work.

Any idea of what changes are applied to my code with Webkit which could make this happen?

Here is my code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cAqyo

Would a Reset work? I thought Bootstrap had one included but maybe it's not enough.

**TL;DR**

It works in Firefox but not in Chrome and mobile
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cAqyo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

```
box-sizing: content-box;
```

to

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

in the .fancy-input class, it works correctly in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works on mobile too now.